# I found a 3-day-old spammer

Tags: support, status-completed, spam, user-accounts

He [answered](https://superuser.com/questions/56122/transferring-videos-from-sony-video-camera-to-pc-via-usb-connection/199336#199336) one of my questions and then I browsed his [answers](https://superuser.com/users/52057/bencody01) only to find out that he is a spammer. All answers are the same and are commending a shareware. I demand deletion of his account.

name: [bencody01](https://superuser.com/users/52057/bencody01)
member for: 3 days

Comment: "Demand deletion" sounds a bit power-mad to me. And now you've outed him in public. Wouldn't this have been better served by flagging one or three of his answers and advising the moderator to look at his other answers?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with posting his nickname here on meta. That's only a nickname, not a valuable info about that person. Besides, I had already flagged that post. I am an enemy of spammers and I won't hesitate to complain about them in public.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What? Where? Can't be?

There is no such thing as spammers on Super User.

Comment: thanks to our moderators! ;)